# Razor pages not update until restart project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, abp

I add Volo.Account module with source code to my solution for update some functionality of Login/Register. When I update page (like Login.cshtml) changes not shown until restart project.

According to [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), I instal `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package and line below to `ConfigureServices` of `{PROJECT}AuthServerModule`, but RuntimeCompilation not working.

```
context.Services.AddRazorPages()
.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you don't need to use `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` in your application. You can get the advantage of ABP's [Virtual File System](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Virtual-File-System) and configure the `AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions` in your application module class:

```cs
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        var hostingEnvironment = context.Services.GetHostingEnvironment();
        var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();

        //other configurations...

        if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            Configure<AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.FileSets.ReplaceEmbeddedByPhysical<AbpAccountWebModule>(Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, string.Format("<web-module-project-path>")));
  
            });
        }
    }
```

You just need to use the `ReplaceEmbeddedByPhysical` method. Check the following links for more info:

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Virtual-File-System#dealing-with-embedded-files-during-development
- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Web/MyProjectNameWebModule.cs#L148

Comment: I add `                options.FileSets.ReplaceEmbeddedByPhysical<AbpAccountWebModule>(Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, string.Format("..{0}..{0}modules{0}Volo.Account{0}src{0}Volo.Abp.Account.Web", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
` and work perfectly! thanks